# GCD of this polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, divisibility

So here is the exact question that i am having trouble on:

"Extend the Euclidean algorithm to polynomials and find the greatest common divisor of:

$3x^5-10x^4-4x^3-14x^2-7x-4$

and

$3x^4+11x^3-5x^2-5x-4$"

Now, i know how to find the gcd using Euclidean's algorithm for all integers as well as polynomials but i am having trouble with this one... I tried wolfram alpha at first and it gave me the gcd of: $3x^2+2x+1$. Then i did it by hand and i keep getting a completely different gcd: $\displaystyle \frac{612}{169}x^2+\frac{408}{169}x+\frac{204}{169}$.

Here is my work for how i used Euclidean's algorithm:

[image: Work for Euclidean's algorithm]

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong [and why] and which one is the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: In $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, you have gotten the same polynomial up to multiplication by $\frac{204}{169}$.  So you have gotten the same GCD in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ up to multiplication by a nonzero constant (i.e., up to associates), which is all you can expect in this case, in terms of uniqueness.

Comment: Ok thanks, and thanks to whoever edited my post for me, i couldn't figure out how to format it properly.

Comment: use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd+%283x%5E5%E2%88%9210x%5E4%E2%88%924x%5E3%E2%88%9214x%5E2%E2%88%927x%E2%88%924+%2C+3x%5E4%2B11x%5E3%E2%88%925x%5E2%E2%88%925x%E2%88%924%29